# What is the meaning of "sure if"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiomatic-language, idioms-in-context

I couldn't find the definition of "sure if" in any dictionary.

What is the meaning of "sure if" in this sentence? "Genuinely modest, but always **sure if** his ambitions and achievements."

[https://www.amazon.com/Sam-Walton-Made-America/dp/0553471120]

Comment: I think **sure** here is the adjective we're all familiar with: **confident**. **He's genuinely modest, but always confident if something something.** That's all that can be said about your incomplete sentence.

Comment: ...unless it's a typo for  _sure of_.

Comment: @KateBunting thanx for comment. I found the meaning of "sure of" from an English dictionary. You are right.